# How can a mutator gene can cause a mutation when it is shut off?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, mutations

defination of "Mutator" - a gene that increases the rate of mutation of one or more other genes.

However, in the book "Molecular Biology of the Cell" (bruce alberts) it states that when a mutator is shut down, then that shut down increases the rate of mutation. How does that process work? It seems to contradict its definition? If the mutator is shut down, then how can it create mutations?

Comment: Please give a reference of that textbook. In a general way, I can say that it works like Trp Operon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trp_operon